# Pyaudio: no method 'get_device_count'

Tags: python-2.7, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I'm using the Python [Speech Recognition library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/) to recognize speech input from the microphone.

This works fine with my default microphone.
This is the code I'm using. According to what I understood of the documentation

> Creates a new Microphone instance, which represents a physical
>   microphone on the computer. Subclass of AudioSource.
>
> If device_index is unspecified or None, the default microphone is used
>   as the audio source. Otherwise, device_index should be the index of
>   the device to use for audio input. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/

The problem is that when I want to get the node with pyaudio.get_device_count() - 1. I'm getting this error.

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_device_count'

So I'm not sure how to configure the microphone to use a usb microphone

```
import pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr

index = pyaudio.get_device_count() - 1
print index

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone(index) as source: 
    audio = r.listen(source) 

try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize(audio))   
except LookupError:                           
    print("Could not understand audio")
```

Comment: Its worth to mention what pyaudio version are you using.

Answer (score 2):

```
myPyAudio=pyaudio.PyAudio()
print "Seeing pyaudio devices:",myPyAudio.get_device_count()
```

Comment: I'm working on the same problem. My line of attack is to find the __init__.py where it creates the Microphone class. I will modify this function: If the input to initialize class Microphone is None, somehow create an AudioSource, corresponding to the card with the microphone, and use that source to iniitialize the Microphone.

Comment: In my case I am up the creek because on my Raspberry Pi the default sound card HAS NO INPUT ABILITY. So I need the microphone to be associated with the USB sound "card", which is a Logitech C310.

Comment: I'm trying to do it work with a BBB. Let me know if you can do it work

Comment: I got it working by calling "arecord" from python. That creates a *.wav audio file which can be processed instead of direct microphone input.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug in the library. I just pushed out a fix in 1.3.1, so this should now be fixed!

Version 1.3.1 retains full backwards compatibility with previous versions.